# How to force cygwin to run specific application when multiple with same name exist?

Tags: python, cygwin

This is what I get in my Cygwin:

```
$ where python
C:\cygwin64\bin\python
C:\Users\eeng1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\eeng1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I want to know these two things:

1. Why does cygwin already contain Python when I did not install it there? The path does not appear to match between the where and which command results.
2. Is there way to remove the Python inside the cygwin bin folder?
3. Why is there a python under WindowsApps folder? I don't remember putting anything Python there actually.

**4. How do I tell Cygwin that it must run the python.exe that is found inside the Python39 folder and not any other!**

Edit:

When I try to uninstall the Python using Cygwin setup that was recommended to me. I get this:

> Problem 1/1 package clang-8.0.1-1 requires python2, but none of the
> providers can be installed Solution 1/2
>
> - allow replacement of clang-8.0.1-1 with clang-5.0.1-2 Solution 2/2 (default)
> - do not ask to deinstall python2-2.7.18-4

It seems that I can't just get rid of the Python2 that exists inside the cygwin bin folder. There is no straight forward way to do this.

Comment: Normally, you'd configure you $PATH to point to directories you want to start commands from. Or, define an alias or a function.

Comment: To answer 1: you probably installed something else that needed python.

Comment: To answer 2: use cygwin's SETUP.EXE to install or remove programs.

Comment: I know about $PATH, its just this cygwin's own bin which I am not sure what to do about. I am stuck as thing stand.

Comment: Using setup to remove the python from cygwin failed

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"?

Comment: ok, I am not able to remove Python 2 since it is required by some other Cygwin package. Please see the edit in the question description.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the cygwin's python? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Please look at result returned by the command which. When I type in Python into the command-line, it does not execute the correct executeable which is stored in folder called Python39

Comment: Why do you need to run the different python?

Answer (score 1):

Under Cygwin `/usr/bin/python` is a link managed by `alternatives`

```
$ alternatives --display python
python - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python2.7 - priority 27
/usr/bin/python3.8 - priority 38
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 36
/usr/bin/python3.7 - priority 37
Current `best' version is /usr/bin/python3.8.
```

If you want to bypass Cygwin python and run the Windows one (with all the risk to broke other Cygwin programs) you have several options:

1. Set alternatives to point to the Windows one
2. Put the `C:\Users\eeng1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` in the PATH before `/usr/bin/`
3. Use a alias for the full windows python.

About removing python2, you can use `cygcheck-dep` package to identify the dependency. On my system:

```
$ cygcheck-dep -q -n python2
 python2: is needed for ( clang clang-analyzer gobject-introspection libfontforge2 libglib2.0-devel libgtk2.0-devel libpeas1.0_0 llvm nghttp2 octave-miscellaneous pulseaudio-equalizer python python-gobject-devel python2-backports.ssl_match_hostname python2-gobject python2-pyqt5 python2-sip )
```

So to remove `python2` I should also remove all the packages than need it.
With `cygcheck-dep -q -N python2`
you will see also all package that recoursive need python2)

Comment: Try using the `py` command to launch windows version of python. At a command prompt, enter `py --help`.